# Get Excel to display "Now" as text

Tags: python, excel, selenium

I'm running a python script that reads a value from the screen and compares it to a value read from an excel spreadsheet.
The problem I'm running into is that the value on the screen is: Now

On the excel sheet, when I have a cell with Now, the value it returns is "Now 2016-07-08 11:18" which causes the comparison to fail.
I've tried changing the format of the cell to text, but it's not solving the problem.

The python command I'm using looks like this:

```
ExcelValue= self.ws.cell(row=i, column=3).value
```

Can anyone please advise on how to solve this?

Comment: Use `'Now` on your Excel (in the formula field), or format as text

Comment: I tried both of those, but I'm still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the current content, format the Excel cell as Text, and enter "Now" in the cell. If you are using POI, make sure the the cell type is string. That should fix it.